# _delay_ms not working with ATmega 16/32

Tags: avr, programming

I had purchased an ATMEGA 16 microcontroller and chaged its fuse bits settings and used internal caliberated RC clock with 1000000.
Changes done in make file and F_CPU. But it do nothing.

***Programme for LED Blinking***

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
int main(void)
 {
   DDRC=0xFF;

  while(1)
       {
        PORTC=0xFF;
   _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTC=0x00;
    _delay_ms(1000);

    }
 }
```

At the same time the ***following programme works fine***.Can somebody helps me out please its urgent.....Did I forgot something to do.....
These problems are same while using external 16Mhz crystal.
  ***Programme for LED Glowing.***

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL


int main(void)
 {
   DDRC=0xFF;

  while(1)
       {
        PORTC=0xFF;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I am surprised that this compiles at all, as you are missing two `#include`:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
 {
   DDRC=0xFF;

  while(1)
       {
        PORTC=0xFF;
   _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTC=0x00;
    _delay_ms(1000);

    }
 }
```

Note that `F_CPU` must be defined before the `#include` - that can be done in code as shown or in the `makefile`.